# Closing a sub form using MDI parent/child forms?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to close a MDI child form inside a parent form with a button click..

I'm using Visual C++

ive try the following

```
            newMDIChild->Close();
            newMDIChild->Cancel = true;
        newMDIChild->Hide();
        newMDIChild->Visible = false;
```

None of which work...

Any ideas?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: .NET 4, its just a series of windows application forms

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this command:

```
this->Close();
```